# Picard's theorem on Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, approximation

I am being asked about the following equation:

$-u'' + L * \sin(u) = f(x)$

with initial conditions

$u(0) = 1, u(1) = 0$

I feel puzzled as there is no initial condition for a derivative of $u$. Can I proceed without it? How do I manage both initial conditions of $u$?

Comment: This is called a [boundary value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem).

Comment: In general, there is no guarantee that there is a solution. For a given initial condition $(u(0),u'(0))$ the solution at time $t=1$, that is $\phi_1(( u(0),u'(0)) )$ is well defined of course, so you are looking for some $u'(0)$ such that  $[\phi_1(( u(0),u'(0)) )]_1 = u(1)$.